# How can I clear cache in Laravel from a hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a script made with laravel installed in my hosting, 3 days ago I changed the images of my site and the favicon, just today the update of the favicon was reflected, but not the images ...

I have tried to put

```
// Clear cache
Route :: get ('/ clear-cache', function () {
     Artisan :: call ('cache: clear');
     return "The cache was cleared";
});
```

in the path: /routes/web.php

But it doesn't work, also try to delete it manually in the folders where the cache is stored and nothing, everything remains the same.

Comment: `Cache::flush();` can empty the cache. No need to call the artisan command. Also there's a lot of loose spaces around your code. The route `/ clear-cache`  might not work as you'd expect because of the space

Comment: This could be cache in your browser. Did you change only content of images?

Comment: Also, why space before "clear"?

Comment: The spacing in your code will cause issues... Keep things compact, unless specified by a style guide... `Route::get('/clear-cache', function () { Artisan::call('cache:clear'); return 'The cache was cleared'; });` (spacing after `function` and `()` is fine, and add linebreaks where appropriate)

Comment: No spaces are required with `Facades` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
     //Clear route cache:
     Artisan::call('route:cache');
     //Clear config cache:
     Artisan::call('config:cache');
     // Clear application cache:
     Artisan::call('cache:clear');
     // Clear view cache:
     Artisan::call('view:clear');
     return 'Cache cleared';
 });
```

Try this code it will clear all cache.

Comment: No, nothing has worked, the truth is that I don't know what I can do anymore ...  :(

Comment: I hope you replaced images in the correct path. I was replacing the image in public folder and site was fetching images from the assets folder.